# A question about Ginibre’s ‘Statistical Ensembles of Complex, Quarternion and Real Matrices.’ A question concerning matrices.

Tags: matrices, random-matrices

Suppose that we have a set $Z_R$ of $N$ by $N$ matrices with real elements. We then focus on those members, $\mathbf{S} \in Z_R$, with all real eigenvalues.

We can diagonalize $\mathbf{S}$ with some orthogonal matrix $\mathbf{X}$
\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{X^{-1}}\mathbf{S}\mathbf{X}
\end{equation*}
So we have
\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{S}=\mathbf{X}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{X^{-1}} \tag{1}
\end{equation*}

Ginibre, Reference 1, says

> Infinitesimal variations $\mathbf{dA},~\mathbf{dX}$ of
> $\mathbf{A},~\mathbf{X}$ produce a variation $\mathbf{ dS}$ of  $ 
>  \mathbf{S}$
>
> \begin{equation*} \mathbf{dS }= \mathbf{X }( \mathbf{dA }+ [\mathbf{dR
>  }, \mathbf{A }]) \mathbf{X^{-1} } \tag{1.4} \end{equation*}
> where $\mathbf{dR }=\mathbf{X^{-1} }  \mathbf{dX }  $

I assume, that for matrices $\mathbf{\alpha },~ \mathbf{\beta }$
\begin{equation*}
[\mathbf{\alpha },~ \mathbf{\beta }] = \mathbf{\alpha } \mathbf{\beta } -  \mathbf{\beta }
 \mathbf{\alpha }
\end{equation*}

I cannot show that (1.4) is correct. My analysis gives, (see other information )
\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{dS }= \mathbf{X }\mathbf{dA }\mathbf{X^{-1} }- \mathbf{A }\mathbf{X^{-1} }\mathbf{dX }+\mathbf{A }\mathbf{dX }\mathbf{X^{-1} } \tag{2}
\end{equation*}

My question is: Is Ginibre’s (1.4) correct?

**Reference**
1,
Jean Ginibre; Statistical Ensembles of Complex, Quaternion, and Real Matrices. J. Math. Phys. 1 March 1965; 6 (3): 440–449. https://doi.org/10.1063/1.1704292

**Other Information**

**Derivation of (2).**

Starting from $\mathbf{(1)}$

\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{S}=\mathbf{X}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{X^{-1}} \tag{1}
\end{equation*}
If  $\mathbf{A} ~\to ~ \mathbf{A}+\mathbf{dA}$,  $\mathbf{X} ~\to ~ \mathbf{X+dX}$ (it is assumed that $\mathbf{dA}$ is a diagonal matrix) then

\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{S+dS}=(\mathbf{X} + \mathbf{dX} ) ( \mathbf{A} +\mathbf{dA}  ) 
(\mathbf{X} + \mathbf{dX})^{-1}  
\end{equation*}

It is also assumed that ( a binomial thing )
\begin{equation*}
(a+x)^n= a^n +na^{n+1}x +\dots
\end{equation*}
can be used with $a$ and $x$ matrices, so that

\begin{equation*}
(\mathbf{X} + \mathbf{dX})^{-1}  = \mathbf{X} ^{-1}  + (-1) \mathbf{X} ^{-2 }\mathbf{dX} =
 \mathbf{X} ^{-1} -\mathbf{X} ^{-2~} \mathbf{dX} 
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{S+dS}=(\mathbf{X} + \mathbf{dX} ) ( \mathbf{A} +\mathbf{dA}  ) 
(\mathbf{X} ^{-1} -\mathbf{X} ^{-2}~ \mathbf{dX} )
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{S+dS}=\mathbf{X} ( \mathbf{A} +\mathbf{dA}  ) 
(\mathbf{X} ^{-1} -\mathbf{X} ^{-2}~ \mathbf{dX} )+ \mathbf{dX} ( \mathbf{A} +\mathbf{dA}  ) 
(\mathbf{X} ^{-1} -\mathbf{X} ^{-2}~ \mathbf{dX} )\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
( \mathbf{A} +\mathbf{dA}  ) ~(\mathbf{X} ^{-1} -\mathbf{X} ^{-2}~ \mathbf{dX} )=
\mathbf{A} \mathbf{X} ^{-1}  +  \mathbf{dA}\mathbf{X} ^{-1}  - \mathbf{A} \mathbf{X} ^{-2}\mathbf{dX} - \mathbf{dA} \mathbf{X} ^{-2} \mathbf{dX} 
\end{equation*}
Using this last equation, in the one just above it, with six terms cancelling, gives $\mathbf{(2)}$

\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{dS }= \mathbf{X }\mathbf{dA }\mathbf{X^{-1} }- \mathbf{A }\mathbf{X^{-1} }\mathbf{dX }+\mathbf{A }\mathbf{dX }\mathbf{X^{-1} } \tag{2}
\end{equation*}

**(2) may be written as.**
\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{dS }= \mathbf{X }\mathbf{dA }\mathbf{X^{-1} }-
 \mathbf{A }( \mathbf{X^{-1} }\mathbf{dX }-\mathbf{dX }\mathbf{X^{-1} }) 
\end{equation*}
i.e.
\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{dS }= \mathbf{X }\mathbf{dA }\mathbf{X^{-1} }-
 \mathbf{A }[ \mathbf{X^{-1} }~,~\mathbf{dX }]  \tag{3}
\end{equation*}

**Ginibre’s Paper.**

This is a very much cited paper, It has been cited over 1,000 times, see at

https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cites=12459902200217406920&as_sdt=2005&sciodt=0,5&hl=en

Ginibre’s $\mathbf{(1.4)}$, is actually part of material about a set $Z_C$, of $N$ by $N$ matrices with complex entries, but is also used after this in the paper, in discussing the set $Z_R$.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is assuming matrices commute. They generally don't.

The second place this error appeared is when you substituted "this last equation, in the one just above it"; you should have ended up with $\mathrm{d}X$s *in front* of other factors, not behind them.

The first place this error occurred is in the "binomial thing." A rational-function / power-series identity which is valid for multiple scalar variables is not necessarily true for matrices, or may need to be written just right. With the socks-and-shoes rule, we can turn it into a valid application of a one-variable identity, though:

$$ (X+\mathrm{d}X)^{-1}=\bigl(X(I+X^{-1}\mathrm{d}X)\bigr)^{-1}=(I+X^{-1}\mathrm{d}X)^{-1}X^{-1} $$

$$ =(I-X^{-1}\mathrm{d}X+\cdots)X^{-1}=X^{-1}+X^{-1}(\mathrm{d}X)X^{-1}. $$

Without knowing the binomial series, we could also reason as follows: if $Y=X^{-1}$, then

$$ Y+\mathrm{d}Y=(X+\mathrm{d}X)^{-1} \implies (X+\mathrm{d}X)(Y+\mathrm{d}Y)=I$$

Multiplying out gives $XY+X\mathrm{d}Y+(\mathrm{d}X)Y=I$. Substituting $Y=X^{-1}$ and solving gives

$$ \mathrm{d}(X^{-1})=X^{-1}(\mathrm{d}X)X^{-1}. $$

Or, we can write $XY=I$ and apply $\mathrm{d}$ as a derivation, use the product rule, and solve.

Now, you can apply $\mathrm{d}$ directly to $S=XAX^{-1}$ as well to get

$$ \mathrm{d}S=(\mathrm{d}X)AX^{-1}+X(\mathrm{d}A)X^{-1}+XA(X^{-1}(\mathrm{d}X)X^{-1}) $$

which you can then check matches equation $(1)$.